# click on green pixel on screen, c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting a system Message in a SAP Software sometimes. This Software is be opened automatic from a c# wpf tool. I got this green hook at the bottom of the Message. Is it possible to find the green pixels on the screen and perform a mouse click on it when it apears?

[image: ScreenPicture]

Comment: "Is it possible?" - In most cases, Yes. There is even some software that does UI automation with help of image recognition. Is it easy, or a good idea? No it is really difficult problem, and any solution is likely to be fragile and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control how many green pixels where will be on-screen so while technically finding green pixels, positioning the mouse and simulating clicks is possible, you should probably not do this.

I'd suggest to look for Accessibility markers that you can use to identify these UI elements (you can do this with [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/windows/overview/) for example) and then use tools like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to automate your interaction.

[image: Accessibility Insights for Windows]